# slapd service is not starting on centos 7

Tags: centos, ldap, openldap

Hi while I was trying to install open-ldap in my centos 7 server, I think I runned yum remove ldap command(I am not sure exactly) and now slap service is not working at all

```
[root@kwephispra28828 etc]# systemctl start slapd
Job for slapd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status slapd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.


[root@kwephispra28828 etc]# journalctl -xe
Dec 09 16:36:04 kwephispra28828 runuser[53027]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user ldap by (uid=0)
Dec 09 16:36:04 kwephispra28828 runuser[53027]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user ldap
Dec 09 16:36:04 kwephispra28828 slapcat[53031]: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
Dec 09 16:36:04 kwephispra28828 slapd[53039]: @(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.44 (Aug 31 2021 14:48:49) $
                                                      mockbuild@x86-02.bsys.centos.org:/builddir/build/BUILD/openldap-2.4.44/openldap-2.4.44/servers/slapd
Dec 09 16:36:05 kwephispra28828 slapd[53039]: main: TLS init def ctx failed: -1
Dec 09 16:36:05 kwephispra28828 slapd[53039]: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
Dec 09 16:36:05 kwephispra28828 slapd[53039]: slapd stopped.
Dec 09 16:36:05 kwephispra28828 slapd[53039]: connections_destroy: nothing to destroy.
Dec 09 16:36:05 kwephispra28828 systemd[1]: slapd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 09 16:36:05 kwephispra28828 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenLDAP Server Daemon.
-- Subject: Unit slapd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit slapd.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Dec 09 16:36:05 kwephispra28828 systemd[1]: Unit slapd.service entered failed state.
Dec 09 16:36:05 kwephispra28828 systemd[1]: slapd.service failed.
Dec 09 16:36:05 kwephispra28828 polkitd[6312]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:53016:5514800560 (system bus name :1.1155728, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconn
lines 2509-2566/2566
```

and this is the systemctl status

```
[root@kwephispra28828 etc]# systemctl status slapd
● slapd.service - OpenLDAP Server Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/slapd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-12-09 16:36:05 +03; 2min 19s ago
     Docs: man:slapd
           man:slapd-config
           man:slapd-hdb
           man:slapd-mdb
           file:///usr/share/doc/openldap-servers/guide.html
  Process: 53039 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/slapd -u ldap -h ${SLAPD_URLS} $SLAPD_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 53022 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/openldap/check-config.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 09 16:36:04 kwephispra28828 slapcat[53031]: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
Dec 09 16:36:04 kwephispra28828 slapd[53039]: @(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.44 (Aug 31 2021 14:48:49) $
                                                      mockbuild@x86-02.bsys.centos.org:/builddir/build/BUILD/openldap-2.4.44/openldap-2.4.44/servers/slapd
Dec 09 16:36:05 kwephispra28828 slapd[53039]: main: TLS init def ctx failed: -1
Dec 09 16:36:05 kwephispra28828 slapd[53039]: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
Dec 09 16:36:05 kwephispra28828 slapd[53039]: slapd stopped.
Dec 09 16:36:05 kwephispra28828 slapd[53039]: connections_destroy: nothing to destroy.
Dec 09 16:36:05 kwephispra28828 systemd[1]: slapd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 09 16:36:05 kwephispra28828 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenLDAP Server Daemon.
Dec 09 16:36:05 kwephispra28828 systemd[1]: Unit slapd.service entered failed state.
Dec 09 16:36:05 kwephispra28828 systemd[1]: slapd.service failed.
```

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Could you source the environment file on a terminal: source /etc/sysconfig/slapd, and then run the command that is displayed in ExecStart: /usr/sbin/slapd -u ldap -h ${SLAPD_URLS} $SLAPD_OPTIONS, and post the results you get on the terminal? The error should appear in there.

Comment: It shows nothing. I checked s/etc/sysconfig/slapd file there is onyl SLAPD_URLS fields is not commented, rest of the file is commented out.

Comment: add -d? and choose one of the options to get extra debugging info